# Bootstrap 4 progress bar is not showing up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm building a table. A couple of the columns require a a progress bar, with a label column on each side. I'm generating this as a component with React, which results in the following HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">
        <span>Current</span>
        <span>3.2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
       <div class="progress">
           <div class="progress-bar w-75" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="69" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 69%; background-color: rgb(52, 125, 241);">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column  justify-content-between" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">
        <span>Day 120</span>
        <span>4.6</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The progress bar does not render, either in my app or in Codepen.

Without all of the surrounding HTML, the progress component renders fine.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the Codepen:

See the Pen [Table cell with Bootstrap progress bar](https://codepen.io/BaruchKogan/pen/YeObdJ/) by Baruch Kogan ([@BaruchKogan](https://codepen.io/BaruchKogan)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Does anyone understand what's going on and why?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, just added one.

Comment: Tried doing that, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: you mentioned codepen sample. where is it ?

Comment: Just added the Codepen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a flexbox issue, not a problem with the progress bar.

In order for the flexbox children of the parent `d-flex flex-row` container to fill across, a width needs to be set on the children. You can use `w-100` to set width:100%, or use `flex-grow:1`.

Problem fixed: https://www.codeply.com/go/kU7OwwmM2I

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="d-flex flex-colum justify-content-between" style="font-size: 0.8rem;"><span>Current</span><span>3.4</span></div>
    <div class="d-block w-100">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="83" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 83%; background-color: rgb(52, 125, 241);"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column  justify-content-between" style="font-size: 0.8rem;"><span>Day 120</span><span>4.1</span></div>
</div>
```

Note: if you want all 3 children to fill equally use `w-100` on all of them, [like on this fork of your codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQVXvd)

---

A simpler **Bootstrap 4 friendly approach** is to use the grid, which requires far less markup. The `row` is display:flex, and the `col` are flex-grow:1...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="font-size: 0.8rem;"><span>Current</span><span>3.4</span></div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="83" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 83%; background-color: rgb(52, 125, 241);"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="font-size: 0.8rem;"><span>Day 120</span><span>4.1</span></div>
</div>
```

Better approach: https://www.codeply.com/go/WFpkiDsJgW

Comment: This is a life saver, I spent almost 7 hours trying everything. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've added lots of `d-flex` classes.

Remove `d-flex` and the progress bar will show up.

Use normal Bootstrap columns instead of `d-flex` divs.

Comment: The issue is that the container element is not the page, but a cell in a table. I can't split it into Bootstrap columns.

Answer (score 1):

add the progress bar's `w-75` class. to its parent container, instead of applying it directly on the progress bar (which has nowhere to stretch to).

https://www.bootply.com/k1XjtaHCxe

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">
        <span>Current</span>
        <span>3.2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-column w-75">
       <div class="progress">
           <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="69" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 69%; background-color: rgb(52, 125, 241);">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-column  justify-content-between" style="font-size: 0.8rem;">
        <span>Day 120</span>
        <span>4.6</span>
    </div>
</div>
```